# Document upload in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office

When we upload any office  document in sharepoint document library do sharepoint make any changes or add properties to the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon the SharePoint application and also the Office version (e.g., use of Document Parsing & Record Center Sites - where doc properties are related to the site content) - see this post for an example & more details: [The Case of the Missing Office Document Properties in SharePoint 2010.](http://www.binarywave.com/blogs/eshupps/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=89cbe813-99f7-4257-a23a-5fefc377336b&ID=250&Web=c7893495-be3b-4d73-9875-28b039760651)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know SharePoint is not making any changes when you upload the document it just extracts the properties matching columns in the library, but when you access the document from a document library SharePoint will add/update these properties in the document.

But the result is the same.
Your document will not be unchanged when you retrieve it later.